# The package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 needs to be reinstalled

Tags: software-installation

when i am trying to install any package, I am getting the following error

The package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Answer (score 1):

The package `libdrm-nouveau2` exists in the official repos. The *:i386* extension is not part of the package name. It denotes that you want to install the 32-bit version of the package. Type:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install libdrm-nouveau2:i386` to force its re-installation.

The *:i386* is not even needed if you have installed the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.  You can safely omit it from the command.

Comment: thanks stormlord..
i tried the above but again it results in the same error :
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libdrm-nouveau2:i386
[sudo] password for harsh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.